# plot convolution in the time domain with octave

Tags: signal-processing, octave, convolution

This plots but the result of conv is a vector of a new length and so `t` is usless to include in plot like `plot(t, z1) %doesn't work!`.

```
t = [-5:.1:10];
unit = @(t) 1.*(t>=0);

h1 = @(t) (3*t + 2).*exp(-3*t).*unit(t);
z1 = conv(unit(t), h1(t));

plot(z1);
```

I want a plot of the convolved signal as a function of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the *shape* argument.  Here's the [spec](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Products-of-Polynomials.html):

> — Function File: conv (a, b) — Function File: conv (a, b, shape)
>   Convolve two vectors a and b.
>
> The output convolution is a vector with length equal to length (a) +
>   length (b) - 1. When a and b are the coefficient vectors of two
>   polynomials, the convolution represents the coefficient vector of the
>   product polynomial.
>
> The optional shape argument may be
>
> shape = "full" Return the full convolution. (default)  shape = "same"
>   Return the central part of the convolution with the same size as a.

so convolve like this:

```
z1 = conv(unit(t), h1(t), "same");
```

And you'll get the same time units as the original.

Comment: Do you know what version shape was added in? I have 3.2.4 on one machine and its provided `conv()` only takes two arguments.

Comment: I don't know, but I last used Octave about 4 years ago, and I think it worked then.  It's been in Matlab for over 10.